# What is the link between the order of the AR process and the order of the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test in case of first differences?

Tags: autoregressive, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller, differences

I realize that in general ( for an AR(p) process ), you should include p-1 lagged differences in the ADF specification (when testing for non-stationarity).

I was recently told, however, that when testing for the non-stationarity of a first differences (that are described by an AR(p) process) your ADF specification should be of an order p. This then implies p lagged differences (of the first differences) in the unit root test.

Does this sound correct to you? And, if so, how can I transform my AR(p) model for first differences to see that it implies an ADF(p)? (I can't see this, I just end up with the regular p-1).

Thanks in advance for your reply!